# Flask-CQLAlchemy DB objects dont have 'query' attribute

Tags: python, flask, cassandra, cql

I am trying to write a flask application with Cassandra. I am using the Flask-CQLAlchemy library to do this and the basic querying supported by the ORM doesn't seem to work.

My code looks something like this :

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    first_name  = db.columns.Text()
    last_name = db.columns.Text()
```

When I open up the terminal and go to Python, I create a new person with

```
person1 = Person(first_name='ABC', last_name='WYZ')
```

It goes through but when I query the Person database with :

```
Person.query.limit(1).all()
```

I get an error saying :

```
AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'query'
```

Is there something else that needs to be added in the CQLAlchemy program?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you try to use `Flask-CQLAlchemy` as `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. But this is different libraries.

To find objects with limit:

```
for p in Person.objects().limit(100):
    print(p)
```

To find by field:

```
print(Person.get(uid='uid_here'))
```

You can find other useful methods [here](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py#L884)

Hope this helps.